# Environment variables with substitution in Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

I'm using environment variables in my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
ENV MEDIAWIKI_VERSION=1.29
ENV MEDIAWIKI_FULL_VERSION=1.29.0
ENV MEDIAWIKI_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/$MEDIAWIKI_VERSION/mediawiki-$MEDIAWIKI_FULL_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN echo $MEDIAWIKI_VERSION \
&&  echo $MEDIAWIKI_FULL_VERSION \
&&  echo $MEDIAWIKI_DOWNLOAD_URL
```

and it is working

```
1.29
1.29.0
https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.29/mediawiki-1.29.0.tar.gz
```

Now I'd like to combine the 3 ENV lines into one.

So I tried

```
FROM alpine
ENV MEDIAWIKI_VERSION=1.29 \
    MEDIAWIKI_FULL_VERSION=1.29.0 \
    MEDIAWIKI_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/$MEDIAWIKI_VERSION/mediawiki-$MEDIAWIKI_FULL_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN echo $MEDIAWIKI_VERSION \
&&  echo $MEDIAWIKI_FULL_VERSION \
&&  echo $MEDIAWIKI_DOWNLOAD_URL
```

But it is not working.  The substitution does not work.

```
1.29
1.29.0
https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki//mediawiki-.tar.gz
```

I also tried with `$$...` and `${...}` and `$${...}` and also with double cotes.  But nothing to do.

What I'm missing ?

My config

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:53:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:51:03 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

docker-compose version 1.15.0, build e12f3b9
docker-py version: 2.4.2
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

Comment: With a single `ENV` statement, you are trying to use `$MEDIAWIKI_VERSION` before it has been defined (because the `ENV` statement hasn't actually completed yet). If you want to use one environment variable to set another, you'll need multiple `ENV` statements.

Comment: That is not supposed to work. In a bash execute `X=2 echo "X is $X"`, it wont set the value.  As @larsks mentioned you need to split your statement into two ENV statements

Comment: Ok I understand my mistake.  Thanks to both of you.